# How to create result from multiple IF results neatly in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to combine multiple results of if statement into a form of a sentence.

Code:

```
=CONCAT("Fail column", IF($T3="No", " T", "")& IF($U3="No", ", U", "") & IF($W3<7, ", W", "") & IF($X3>3, ", X", "") & IF($AE3="No", ", AE", "") & IF($AF3="No", ", AF", ""))
```

Sample data :
[image]

If the first statement returns blank, the next statement would not show the comma at the beginning. And let say all pass, they would be shown as "Yes".

My expected output can be:

1. Fail column T, U, W, X, AE, AF
2. Fail column U, W, X, AE, AF
3. Fail column T
4. Fail column W, X
5. Yes

Comment: Please can you include some sample data with expected output. Btw, if you have `CONCAT` you also have `TEXTJOIN` which might come in handy. Also, you either use Excel or GS, please make a choice since they truely are different apps.

Comment: @JvdV Hi, edited the question.. Btw, how to know better choice when using these two?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could try:

[image]

Formula in `R3`:

```
=IF(OR(T3="No",U3="No",W3<7,X3>3,AE3="No",AF3="No"),"Fail column: "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(T3="No","T",""),IF(U3="No","U",""),IF(W3<7,"W",""),IF(X3>3,"X",""),IF(AE3="No","AE",""),IF(AF3="No","AF","")),"Yes")
```

The key here is `TEXTJOIN` instead of `CONCAT` to exclude any empty values from the concatenated string.

<sub>**Note:** Excel and Google Spreadsheets are two different apps and the functions are not always exchangeable. Your question's title suggests that you are actually using Excel, however your tags include GS.</sub>

Comment: Any luck with this @KrengKongkeng

Answer (score 0):

correct formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(IF(
 (T3:T="yes")*(U3:U="yes")*((W3:W<7)*(W3:W<>""))*(X3:X>3)*(AE3:AE="yes")*(AF3:AF="yes"), 
 "yes", "Fail column: "&
 IF(T3:T="no",            "T, ", )&
 IF(U3:U="no",            "U, ", )&
 iF(W3:W>=7,              "W, ", )&
 IF((X3:X<=3)*(X3:X<>""), "X, ", )&
 IF(AE3:AE="no",          "AE, ", )&
 IF(AF3:AF="no",          "AF, ", )), ", $|Fail column: $", ))
```

[image: 0]